# Ember error: Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super when using Ember.ArrayController.create( ...)

Tags: ember.js

I am following a book tutorial and this is the block of code thats causing the following errors.

Assertion failed: Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super. ember-1.3.2.js:3285

Uncaught TypeError: Property '_super' of object [object Object] is not a function application.js:6

Code block causing errors:

```
MovieTracker.moviesController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    init: function() {
        this._super();

        var list = [

            MovieTracker.Movie.create({
                title: 'Movie 1',
                rating: 4
            }),
            MovieTracker.Movie.create({
                title: 'Movie 2',
                rating: 5
            })];

        this.set('content', list);

    }
});
```

I am new to Ember and have a basic understand of Ember's object model, anything that I have read regarding this._super() error involves using the Mixins built into ember.  Im not sure how this applies to building an Ember.ArrayController object. The error tells me that _super() is no longer supported. I've been following through the tutorial pretty well up until this point. Im not sure how to proceed from here.

Im using Ember 1.3.2 and the book tutorial Im following is 
"Ember.js Application Development How-to" and this example is on pg 25

I've seen suggestions to return this._super(); at the end of the init method but that still results in an error.

EDIT:
I realized that I was using an older version of Ember, so I upgraded to 1.4.0 but I still get the same ._super() error, however  its only one error instead of two:

Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super. ember-1.4.0.js:73

Again it says I that _super is no longer supported when creating objects, but how do I deal with that using the ArrayController.create method?

Answer (score 0):

`s/Ember.ArrayController.create/Ember.ArrayController.extend` . No need to create instances of `controller`. Ember takes care of instantiating them at runtime.

If you need to intialize props on instances, use `Em.Object.createWithMixins`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks selva-G for the answer.  your solution did remove the errors however it did cause issues at a later point in the tutorial :(

I was able to fix this issue by creating the object and then setting the values that I needed.

It appears this script in the tutorial was trying to instantiate and set the values at the same time. I changed my code to the following:

```
MovieTracker.moviesController = Ember.ArrayController.create();

MovieTracker.moviesController.set('content', [

            MovieTracker.Movie.create({
                title: 'Movie 1',
                rating: 4
            }),
            MovieTracker.Movie.create({
                title: 'Movie 2',
                rating: 5
            })
        ]);
```

This allowed me to use

MovieTracker.moviesController.get('length');

and have it return 2

At this point, I've run into a few issues with this book...  I think its time to move on to a better book :(